# Merge all the data within the (.....) in one line in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script i need some help i have one SQL file like

```
SELECT DISTINCT  F1.COL1,
F1.COL5 ADDRESS ,
    COALESCE(COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3,
    COL4),
F1.COL7
FROM TABLE1 F1
```

I need to print this in one line like

```
SELECT DISTINCT  F1.COL1,
F1.COL5 ADDRESS ,
COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4),
F1.COL7
FROM TABLE1 F1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed :

```
sed '/(/{:a;N;s/^ *//;s/\n *//;/)/!{ba}}' file
```

To edit file *in place*, add the `-i` option :

```
sed -i '/(/{:a;N;s/^ *//;s/\n *//;/)/!{ba}}' file
```

All lines starting with `(` are joined until next line containing `)`.

Comment: Hi Kenavoz, i have used this command but i am getting the output in one line like.......SELECT DISTINCT  F1.COL1,F1.COL5 ADDRESS ,COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4),F1.COL7 FROM TABLE1 F1.   i want in different line as given above. Thank you for your help. please help me if there is any other way